# Using for-loops in R to process several columns in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to edit 50 columns in my data frame into dummy variables depending on an exact match with a given vector of 50 values using a for-loop function. 
I never used loop functions before and can't figure out how to do it.

I first wanted to code this "by hand" for each of the 50 columns like that:

```
dBGK1a <- as.numeric(BGK1a == BGKright[1])
dBGK2a <- as.numeric(BGK2a == BGKright[2])
dBGK3a <- as.numeric(BGK3a == BGKright[3])
....
dBGK50a <- as.numeric(BGK50a == BGKright[50])
```

As this is very tedious i tried to come up with a for-loop, that can handle this.

```
for(i in 1:50) {
for (j in seq(from = 348, to = 448, by = 2)){
  data1[j] <- as.numeric(data1[j] == BGKright[i])
    }
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work since i get the value "0" in every column over every observation.

data1 is my data frame. Here is a shorter version of the data frame:

```
dput(head(data1[348:354], 20))

structure(list(BGK1a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2), BGK1b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 100, 99, 89, 
50), BGK2a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), BGK2b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 50, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, 50, 96, 62, 93, 50), BGK3a = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2), BGK3b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 50, 85, 82, 74), BGK4a = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What the loop should do is select the respective value of "BGKright" with "i" and the column to process with "j". Note that "j" needs to jump 2 steps every loop because i only need to process every second column (from column 348 to column 448).

I would appreciate any help regarding this loop and other solutions that are possible for this task without loops.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your data using `dput(YOURDATA)` or if it's large do`dput(head(YOURDATA))`

Comment: You are missing a close parenthesis in the second `for`. And this is almost surely possible to do in a (much) more effective way, please post `dput(head(BGKright, 20))` and the same with `data1`.

Comment: `dput(head(BGKright, 20)):
    c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)`

   ` dput(head(data1, 20))` is too long to post it here.

Comment: @RuiBarradas i corrected the paranthesis mistake and i don't get an error message anymore. It still doesn't seem to work since the loop changes every value in column "j" to "0".

Comment: Could you edit your question with a sample of the data e.g. `dput(data[1:20,])`. In your case, if you want to edit multiple columns that meet a certain condition the `mutate_if` function from `dplyr` is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i used `BGKa=select(data1[348:448],ends_with("a"))` to make a new data frame with only the relevant columns.

Then i used the for-loop to create the dummies.

```
for(i in 1:50) {
    BGKa[i]=as.numeric(BGKa[i]==BGKright[i])
  }
```

Seems to work. Ty for help.